# Matplotlib troubleshooting, matplotlib.pyplot.xlim()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having difficulty understanding how `matplotlib.pyplot.xlim()` works.

I am plotting a simple plot of x values vs y values. The y values are numerical points in the range of 100-600. The x values are of magnitude `e-09` to `e-13`. So, I plot x against y. This is my plot, with generic pseudocode

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.array
y = np.array

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylim(0,400)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can tell, there's plenty of structure between 0 and 0.5. I would like to look at that.

So, I try

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,0.5)
plt.ylim(0,400)
plt.show()
```

The output plot is completely blank. I see nothing.

So, I try, xlim= -1 to +1

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(0,400)
plt.show()
```

This is the output plot.

[image]

Using the origninal plot, how can I set the x-axis to see the actual data?

Answer (score 2):

As you clearly mentioned

> The x values are of magnitude e-09 to e-13.

So if you want to see the values that lie within `1e-8` and `0.5e-9` you should do:

```
plt.xlim(1e-8,0.5e-9)
```

instead of

```
plt.xlim(0,0.5)
```

where you have no values to show as the values of x are within e-09 to e-13.

Answer (score 1):

If your x-values are of magnitude of `1e-9` till `1e-13` you have completely different length scales. In this case a logarithmic axis may be appropriate. Note that this works only if all x-values are strictly positive.

```
plt.xscale('log')
```